# How to find upper and lower bound

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, positive-definite

Let $\Sigma \in S_{++}^n$ be a symmteric positive definte matrix with all diagonal entries one. Let $U \in R^{n \times k_1}$, $W \in R^{n \times k_2}$, $\Lambda \in R^{k_1 \times k_1}$ and $T \in R^{k_2 \times k_2}$, where $\Lambda$ and $T$ are both diagonal matrix with positive elements, and $n > k_2 > k_1$. We also know $\text{trace}(\mathbf{\Lambda}) = \mu \times \text{trace}(\mathbf{T})$ and sum of absolute values of all the elements of $U$ is less than $W$. Then how can I find upper and lower bound on-

\begin{align*}
\frac{\|\Sigma -  UTU^\top\|_F^2}{\|\Sigma -  W\Lambda W^\top\|_F^2}
\end{align*}

in terms of $\mu$, $W$, $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma$. Assume that $\|\Sigma \|_F^2 \geq \|UTU^\top \|_F^2$ and $\| \Sigma\|_F^2 \geq \|W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2$

Answer (score 1):

We first find an upper bound on $\|UTU^\top \|_F^2$ in terms of $W$ and $\Lambda$-

\begin{align*}
\|UTU^\top \|_F^2 &\leq \| U\|_F^4 \|T \|_F^2 \\
& \leq \frac{1}{\mu} \| W\|_F^4 \|\Lambda \|_F^2 \\
\end{align*}

Now, assuming that $\|\Sigma \|_F^2 \geq \| UTU^\top \|_F^2$ and $\|\Sigma \|_F^2 \geq \| W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2$

\begin{align*}
\|\Sigma\|_F^2 - \| UTU^\top \|_F^2 \leq \|\Sigma - UTU^\top \|_F^2 \leq \|\Sigma \|_F^2+\| UTU^\top \|_F^2 \\
\|\Sigma\|_F^2 - \frac{1}{\mu} \| W\|_F^4 \|\Lambda \|_F^2 \leq \|\Sigma - UTU^\top \|_F^2 \leq \|\Sigma \|_F^2+\frac{1}{\mu} \| W\|_F^4 \|\Lambda \|_F^2 \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\|\Sigma\|_F^2 - \frac{1}{\mu} \| W\|_F^4 \|\Lambda \|_F^2}{\|\Sigma - W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2} \leq \frac{\|\Sigma - UTU^\top \|_F^2}{{\|\Sigma - W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2}} \leq \frac{\|\Sigma \|_F^2+\frac{1}{\mu} \| W\|_F^4 \|\Lambda \|_F^2}{{\|\Sigma - W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2}} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\|\Sigma\|_F^2 - \frac{1}{\mu} \| W\|_F^4 \|\Lambda \|_F^2}{\|\Sigma\|_F^2 + \|W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2} \leq \frac{\|\Sigma - UTU^\top \|_F^2}{{\|\Sigma - W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2}} \leq \frac{\|\Sigma \|_F^2+\frac{1}{\mu} \| W\|_F^4 \|\Lambda \|_F^2}{{\|\Sigma\|_F^2 - \|W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2}} \\
\end{align*}
Assume that $c\|\Sigma \|_F^2 = \| W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2$ where $0 \leq c\leq 1$, we get

\begin{align*}
\frac{\|\Sigma\|_F^2 - \frac{1}{\mu} \| W\|_F^4 \|\Lambda \|_F^2}{(1+c)\|\Sigma\|_F^2 } \leq \frac{\|\Sigma - UTU^\top \|_F^2}{{\|\Sigma - W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2}} \leq \frac{\|\Sigma \|_F^2+\frac{1}{\mu} \| W\|_F^4 \|\Lambda \|_F^2}{{(1-c)\|\Sigma\|_F^2 }} \\
\end{align*}
As $W$, $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma$ are fixed, let $\frac{\|W \|_F^4 \| \Lambda\|_F^2}{\|\Sigma \|_F^2} = t$, then we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1 - \frac{t}{\mu}}{(1+c) } \leq \frac{\|\Sigma - UTU^\top \|_F^2}{{\|\Sigma - W\Lambda W^\top \|_F^2}} \leq \frac{1 + \frac{t}{\mu}}{(1-c) } \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

So we will search for extremes of the function

$$ f(\mu, W, \Lambda, \Sigma) =
\frac{\|\Sigma -  UTU^\top\|_F^2}{\|\Sigma -  W\Lambda W^\top\|_F^2}
$$

We note that the denominator is fully defined by the parameters of the function, so for the purposes of optimization it is just a constant, let's call it $K$. Also, we can explicitly insert that $T$ is diagonal, namely $T_{ij} = t_i \delta_{ij}$. We can write an optimization problem as follows: Maximize or minimize the L2 norm of some difference

$$ f(\mu, W, \Lambda, \Sigma) = \frac{1}{K}
\sum_{ij} \biggl(\Sigma_{ij} -  \sum_k t_kU_{ik}U_{kj} \biggr)^2 \rightarrow \max or \min
$$

subject to constraints:

$$\sum_i t_i = \frac{1}{\mu} \sum_i \Lambda_{ii} = \alpha$$

and

$$|U|_1 < |W|_1 = \beta$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known constants.

This problem is effectively [Lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) regularization with an additional equality constraint. AFAIK, regularization problems of this kind typically are solved numerically, which means that explicit analytical solutions are not available.

Comment: I am looking for upper and lower bound which can be found analytically, and the bounds need to be super strict.

Comment: @DushyantSahoo I see. I am sorry, I misunderstood the question. I wrongly assumed that the goal was to find the maximum and minimum value, which is much more strict than an upper or a lower bound.

Comment: No worries, I wrote a solution, but I am not sure how correct it is.